# HTML encoding issue: Is it possible to have multiple charset encoding inside HTML

Tags: html, c++, utf-8, character-encoding

I am creating a HTML file from a c++ code which can have multiple charset encodings like iso-2022-jp, utf-8 etc. Is there any way through which we can handle this?

Can I have multiple meta tag for each of its segment? I can have multiple html tags inside one HTML file as well.

It is not possible to convert each segment of HTML into a common encoding say utf-8 because there are n number of possible charset encodings and having a common algo to convert them all is not that feasible. So I was hoping if there is anyway through which I can assign specified character encoding for each segment and browser can accordingly convert it.

If I am using any 1 character encoding then it seems to be working fine but my file can have multiple encoding.

Comment: You can use `frame` or `iframe` in a container HTML to include different HTML that have different charset encoding.  (I'm an advocate of [UTF-8 Everywhere](http://utf8everywhere.org/), but if you have a special situation perhaps that's just not a viable option.)

Comment: Why? it should not be difficult to convert to one encoding, server side. And modern HTML (HTML5) now is utf-8